# pci compliance c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for implemeneting pci compliance security for storing CustomerID.
 i am encrypting the CustomerID storing in DB.But when a customer requests to
my webservice, I will encryt the customerID  pass it to webservice and when the customerID reches my webservice , it should be decrypted.but i am right now storing the key for encrytion in webconfig.ie not secure Any better pci compliance security measures i can use in c#.Any links for implementing pci compliance security.IS hardware security module is an option.

Any suggestion and links appreciated.

regards

supriya

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have some research to do.

I'm not sure what a customerID is and why it needs to be encrypted. PCI deals with security standards around payment transactions.

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/index.php

You maybe thinking about web application security. Lots of information from OWASP.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, what is customerID?  If it is the customer's credit or debit card number, then PCI applies and it should be encrypted when stored with strong encryption and key management.

Comment: In future, please don't add signatures to your answers. :-)